# Unable to verify password using password_verify

Tags: php, ajax

WHen user clicks submit button, ajax will pass data to a php scripts to check if login valid or invalid.

Below, password is not verified. The data passed(email,password) to the checkLogin class are correct, because other data can be retreived using the email address.It's only when it comes to

```
$flag=false;
    if (password_verify($this->password, $hashAndSalt)) {
        $flag=true;
    }
```

its  returning false. I couldn't spot the mistake.Can anyone see what is wrong in my script?

js

```
/*login user*/
 $("document").ready(function(){
    $("#login-user").submit(function(){
        alert("submited");            
      var data = {
        "action": "test"
      };
      data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "text",
        url: "login-this-user.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);

        }
      });//end success
      return false;
    });//end form
  });
```

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');
include('class.login.php');

//$return = $_POST;
$return ='{"email":"jane@ymail.com","pass":"jane","action":"test"}';

//$return['json']= json_encode($return);
  //  
  //below code to store in database 
$data = json_decode($return, true);
$login = new checkLogin();
$return_value = $login->checkLogin($data["email"],$data["pass"]);

echo $return_value;

  ?>
```

class to check login

```
 <?php
 class checkLogin
{
   public $email;
   public $password;
   public $userId;

   public $salt;
   public $hpass;



    public function __construct()
    {

    }
    public function checkLogin($param1, $param2)
    {
        $this->email=$param1;
        $this->password=$param2;

        $sql = "SELECT *FROM agency WHERE  agency_email='{$this->email}'";
        $statement = connection::$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        while( $row = $statement->fetch()) {
        echo "salt ".$salt=$row['agency_salt'];
        echo "hash ".$hashAndSalt=$row['agency_pass'];

         $user_id=$row['agency_id'];

        }
        $flag=false;
        if (password_verify($this->password, $hashAndSalt)) {
            $flag=true;
        }

        return $flag;
    }


}
 ?>
```

Table structure
[image]

Hashing when signing up user and storing password:

```
/*....salting starts........*/
$cost = 10;
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
//$salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;
$options = array('cost' => $cost,'salt' => $salt);

//$password = crypt($data['password'], $salt);
$hash = password_hash($data['passsword'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT,$options);
  /*..........salting ends..............*/
```

Comment: where's the password_verify function?

Comment: @cylua2 check checkLogin function

Comment: Check the [`password_hash()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). It expressly says not to use your own salt as the `password_hash()` func will do that itself

Comment: Also without seeing _How you create the hashed password, its difficult to see what might be wrong._ **Show you hashing script as well**

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I added my hashing script in my post..please refer :)

Comment: Dont see anything obvious **other than no error checking on the `->execute()`** So maybe is this `SELECT *FROM`, put a space between `*` and `FROM`

Comment: I have no idea what exactly is happening or not happening or what you expect to be happening. There's too much code with too little explanation to comprehend what problem you think you're having.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, the select from is working and that's why I can get values within the while loop. But when verifying password keyed in against the one stored in the db, is returning false.

Comment: Ok the other option is that the database column is not long enough to store the complete hashed password